# Probability that we must fix edge or corner to solve a random assembled Rubik's Cube

Tags: probability, rubiks-cube

I have a 3x3x3 Rubik's Cube. I disassemble it and assemble again in a random way. We've already known that the probability that we can solve it without have to fix any corner or edge is $1/12$. But what is the probability to solve that random assembled Cube:

**a.** Without have to fix any corner? (So we can fix edge, if necessary)

**b.** Without have to fix any edge? (So we can fix corner, if necessary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor $1/12$ that a randomly assembled cube is solvable comes from $1/3$ that you do not need to rotate a corner, $1/2$ that you do not need to rotate an edge, and $1/2$ that you do not need to swap the locations of two edges to produce an even permutation.  This is described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube#Permutations).